# Warning: forwardRef render functions accept exactly two parameters: props and ref. Did you forget to use the ref parameter?native base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have this warning when starting a new expo native base js project
native base 3.2.0 expo 4.12.0  every package is good no problem when running the project has this error:-

`````
at node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:315:4 in printWarning
at node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:287:16 in error
at node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1424:13 in forwardRef
at node_modules/native-base/src/components/composites/Skeleton/SkeletonCircle.tsx:12:20 in <global>
at node_modules/native-base/src/components/composites/Skeleton/index.tsx:3:0 in <global>
at node_modules/native-base/src/components/composites/index.ts:37:0 in <global>
at node_modules/native-base/src/index.tsx:7:0 in <global>
at App.js:2:0 in <global>
at node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in <global>
at http://packager.gi-qyq.anonymous.my-furniture.exp.direct/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:202324:3 in global code````
`````

Comment: I get this too and upvoted the question but you should clarify: this is a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 12):

Update native-base to 3.2.1.

```
"dependencies": {
     "native-base": "^3.2.1"  
},
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any reason this may fix it? I'm still getting the issues on 3.2.0

Comment: The right version is `3.2.1-rc.1` and I confirm this does make the stack trace go away.

Comment: I can confirm it works, but I am interested in what was changed that fixes the ref forwarding (what element was it about) ?

Comment: In the meantime native-base 3.2.1 was released. I can confirm it too. Updating fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think this question is not related to native-base. forwardRef is hook used to access child DOM elements from a parent component. You cannot send ref as a props to a child component. You have to set forwardRef hook with props and ref in child functional component.

```
//Child Component
const Child = forwardRef(({name},ref) => {
return(
<p>{ref.current}</p>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

are you using react-navigation 6.x? if so try using hooks, like useRoute, useNavigation, instead of passing  them as props.

Comment: I do not use react-navigation else .that is the fresh project 'hello World' not using anything